# Spring Kafka and Transactions

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-transactions, spring-kafka

I'd like to use Spring Kafka with Transactions but I don't really understand how it is supposed to be configured and how it works.

Here is my configuration

```
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

This config is used in a DefaultKafkaProducerFactory with transaction id prefix:

```
defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("my_app.");
```

**Problem 1 :**

How am I supposed to chose this transaction id prefix ?
If I understand correctly, this prefix is used by spring to generate a transactional id for each producer created.

Why couldn't we just use "UUID.randomUUID() ?

**Problem 2 :**

If the producer is destroyed, it will generate a new transactional id.
Therefor, if the application crash, on restart it will reuse old transactional id.

Is that normal ???

**Problem 3 :**

I'm using an application deployed on cloud which can be automatically scaled up/down.
This means my prefix can not be fixed since all my producers on each instances will have transactional id in conflict.

Should I add a random part in it ?
Do I need to recover the same prefix when an instance is scaled down/up or crash and restart ?

**Problem 4 :**

Last but not least, we are using credentials for our Kafka.
This does not seems to work :

```
Current ACLs for resource `TransactionalId:my_app*`:
    User:CN... has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
```

How should I set my ACLs knowing that my transactional ids are generated ?

**Edit 1**

After further reading, if I understand correctly.

If you have a C0(consumer) reading from P0(partition).If the broker start a consumer rebalance.
P0 could be assigned to another consumer C1.
This consumer C1 should use the same transaction id than then previous C0 to prevent duplicate (Zombies fencing) ?

How do you achieve this in spring-kafka ? The transaction id seems to have nothing to do with the consumer and thus the partition read.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can't use a random TID because of the zombie fencing - if the server crashes you could have a partial transaction in the topic which will never be completed and nothing more will be consumed from any partitions with a write for that transaction.
2. That is by design - for the above reason.
3. Again, you can't randomize; for the above reason.

Cloud Foundry, for example, has an environment variable that indicates the instance index. If you are using a cloud platform that doesn't include something like that, you would have to simulate it somehow. Then, use it in the transaction id:

```
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=foo-${instance.index}-
```

4. ACLs - I can't answer that; I am not familiar with kafka permissions; might be better to ask a separate question for that.
5. I think we need to add some logic to Spring to ensure the same transaction id is always used for a particular topic/partition.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/800#issuecomment-419501929

**EDIT**

Things have changed since this answer (KIP-447); if your brokers are 2.5.0 or later - see. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#exactly-once and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#exactly-once

Comment: 1) Tested a bit, and if I'm not wrong, transaction will timeout. Thus leading the consumers to skip the produced messages.
2) Don't really understand the design here. If the producer crash within the application without causing an application restart. The id will move to 1 thus leading the id 0 with zombies ? Till the app restart ?
3) Not sure I can get an instance index but i'll dig out. Anyway the 5) is more important.
4) Ok
5) Thanks for the issue, was going to create one

Comment: 1) Ah, yes, it behaved as I described when I tested it but, yes, I guess it will timeout (although the default timeout is 15 minutes :D 2) Good point; we need to reuse crashed ids. But 5) will be the proper solution.

Comment: Just for information, I used a breakpoint on JVM to stop one consumer A. After like 5 seconds (didnt really mesured) the other consumer B was reasigned the partition and thus consumed the message. The final consumer C (as expected) didn't read the message from B. And after like 30 secondes, the final consumer C finally read the message from B. After resuming consumer A, the consumer C still didnt read it. The timeout seems shorter than 15 min for me

Comment: 1.3.7, 2.0.6 and 2.1.10 containing the fix are in maven central.

Comment: Question which talks about transaction timeouts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460688/kafka-ignoring-transaction-timeout-ms-for-producer

Comment: Things have changed since this answer; if your brokers are 2.5.0 or later - see. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#exactly-once and  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#exactly-once