# Kafka ignoring `transaction.timeout.ms` for producer

Tags: apache-kafka

I configure the producer to 10-second timeout using the `transaction.timeout.ms` property. However, it seems that the transaction is aborted after 60 seconds, which is much longer.

See the following program:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", brokerConnectionString);
properties.setProperty("transactional.id", "my-transactional-id");
properties.setProperty("transaction.timeout.ms", "5000");

// start the first producer and write one event
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer =
        new KafkaProducer<>(properties, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
producer.initTransactions();
producer.beginTransaction();
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("topic", "value"));
// note the transaction is left non-completed

// start another producer with different txn.id and write second event
properties.setProperty("transactional.id", "another-transactional-id");
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer2 =
        new KafkaProducer<>(properties, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
producer2.initTransactions();
producer2.beginTransaction();
producer2.send(new ProducerRecord<>("topic", "value2"));
producer2.commitTransaction();

// consume the events using read-committed
Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
consumerProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", brokerConnectionString);
consumerProps.setProperty("group.id", "my-group");
consumerProps.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
consumerProps.setProperty("isolation.level", "read_committed");
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = 
        new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
consumer.subscribe(singleton("topic"));
while (true) {
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1))) {
        logger.info(record.toString());
    }
}
```

The `value2` is printed after about 60 seconds, which is the default value for the `transaction.timeout.ms` parameter. Do I understand the property incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the course of writing the question I found the answer. Broker is configured to check timed out producers every 60 seconds, so the transaction is aborted at next check. This property configures it: `transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms`. I started the broker just before the test, that's why it always took about 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for this.  You should accept it as the answer.  Did setting the cleanup interval to 10000 work for you?

Comment: A lower value will roll back transactions more quickly, but will also give producers less time to finish their transactions, so it's a trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Oliv.  You might want to add that to you answer.

Comment: Hello @Oliv, do you know how can I change this value running a kafka over docker?
I tried setting this value as an enviroment variable but my broker didn't recognize it

Comment: Just found out. We have to rename according to docker configuration parameters naming rules: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#ak-configuration
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_ABORT_TIMED_OUT_TRANSACTION_CLEANUP_INTERVAL_MS