# ProducerFencedException after kafka consumer group rebalancing

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, transactions, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I cannot comment on similar topic: 
[TransactionId prefix for producer-only and read-process-write - ProducerFencedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504481/transactionid-prefix-for-producer-only-and-read-process-write-producerfencedex)
so I will ask a new question.

Use case:

- One topic with 2 partitions
- Spring @KafkaListener with concurrency=1 (default) in consumer-group "sample-consumer-group"
- Two instances of the same application - both with the same "transaction-id-prefix"

1) I start first app instance (lets call it "instance1" - evenrything is ok - single consumer subscribes to both partitions. Log:

`o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : sample-consumer-group: partitions assigned: [sampleTopic-1, sampleTopic-0]`

2) I start second app instance (instance2) - everything semms ok - log from this instance:

`o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : sample-consumer-group: partitions assigned: [sampleTopic-1]`

log from "instance1":

```
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : sample-consumer-group: partitions revoked: [sampleTopic-1, sampleTopic-0]
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : sample-consumer-group: partitions assigned: [sampleTopic-0]
```

Still seems ok...
But, when I then try to send message to any other topic (not from any kafkaListener, but from some @Transactional method - so this is producer only transaction) the following errors occur:

```
ERROR 4395 --- [roducer-tx-prefix-0] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-tx-prefix-0, transactionalId=tx-prefix-0] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.

ERROR 4395 --- [roducer-tx-prefix-0] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='sync-register' and payload='2020-04-21T13:52:12.148412Z' to topic anotherTopic
```

So Is it related to the problem that I should have separate transaction-id-prefix for each instance for producer only transactions ? If yes, what is the current status of this and how to achieve this without using separate kafkaTemplate for for consumer started and producer started transactions ?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#transaction-id-prefix).

> As mentioned in the overview, the producer factory is configured with this property to build the producer transactional.id property. There is rather a dichotomy when specifying this property in that, when running multiple instances of the application, it must be the same on all instances to satisfy fencing zombies (also mentioned in the overview) when producing records on a listener container thread. However, when producing records using transactions that are not started by a listener container, the prefix has to be different on each instance. Version 2.3, makes this simpler to configure, especially in a Spring Boot application. In previous versions, you had to create two producer factories and KafkaTemplate s - one for producing records on a listener container thread and one for stand-alone transactions started by kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction() or by a transaction interceptor on a @Transactional method.
>
> Now, you can override the factory’s transactionalIdPrefix on the KafkaTemplate and the KafkaTransactionManager.
>
> When using a transaction manager and template for a listener container, you would normally leave this to default to the producer factory’s property. This value should be the same for all application instances. For transactions started by the template (or the transaction manager for @Transaction) you should set the property on the template and transaction manager respectively. This property must have a different value on each application instance.

Comment: Ok, but the documentation is not clear enought, it states: "you can override the factory’s transactionalIdPrefix on the KafkaTemplate and the KafkaTransactionManager.". How to do it ? Manually for every kafkaTemplate invocation in producer only transaction ? Do I have to set it on the template only or also on the transaction manager ? Could You give any sample ? Because I would rather expect to configure it once somehow - so that I don't need to remember to set it for every invocation. The same kafkaTemplate can be used also in consumer started transactions.

Comment: You don't need to "set it for every invocation". It just works; when the transaction is started by the transaction manager, the template participates in the existing transaction (with the transactional.id from either the producer factory or the TM, if set); for a producer-initiated transaction, the `transactionId` configured on the template itself (if set) is used. In most cases (one TM, one template) you would just set the override on the template to support both consumer- and producer-initiated transactions in the same application.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So for producer-initiated transactions to work properly in multi instance environment I simply need to invoke kafkaTemplate.settransactionIdPrefix method during application startup (KafkaTemplate creation) and set it to some unique value per application instance ?

Comment: One more question -  I deploy mi services on k8s.  As I understand it correctly (from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220225/spring-kafka-and-transactions ) - I can't simply choose random transactionIdPrefix for producer starter transactions. it should be somehow unique instance index ?  But what if I want to decrease number of instances ? From 3 to 2 for example. Partial transactions from instance number "3" will also never be completed ?

Comment: You can use a randomized transaction id or an index; doesn't really matter; if the instance is shutdown in an orderly fashion, the transaction will complete; if not, it will time out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working workaround I've figured out, if you use Kafka < 2.5 and you have to satisfy the requirement of having static transaction id-s for consumer-based transactions, with random transaction ids for producer-based:

> There is rather a dichotomy when specifying this property in that, when running multiple instances of the application, it must be the same on all instances to satisfy fencing zombies (also mentioned in the overview) when producing records on a listener container thread. However, when producing records using transactions that are not started by a listener container, the prefix has to be different on each instance.

```java
public class TransactionSourceAwareKafkaProducerFactory<K, V> extends DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<K, V> {

    public TransactionSourceAwareKafkaProducerFactory(Map<String, Object> configs) {
        super(configs);
    }

    @NonNull @Override
    public Producer<K, V> createProducer(String txIdPrefixArg) {
        if (isProducerBasedTransation())
            return super.createProducer(/** use some random id here **/);
        else
            return super.createProducer(txIdPrefixArg);
    }

    protected boolean isConsumerBasedTransation() {
        return TransactionSupport.getTransactionIdSuffix() != null;
    }

    protected boolean isProducerBasedTransation() {
        return !isConsumerBasedTransation();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've also started a thread here to check if it shouldn't be supported natively by Spring Kafka https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2015